# Automatic variable naming

Tags: automation, subscript, variable

I am trying to construct a complicated code in which I need to name a lot of variables and their definitions.

For Example:

[image]

The problem is as follow:

Once I insert new variable in between two, I have to re-number the subscripts number in the SS & ss. I**s there a way to make this automatic numbering?**

Keeping in mind that if I re-execute the same part of code the numbering must be the same.

Answer (score 5):

Subscripts are evil. Why don't you use an `Association`? This would get you rid of the whole numbering business. This could look like this:

```
value = Association[
   "grav" -> 9.81,
   "L" -> 100 10^6
   ];
help = Association[
   "grav" -> "gravitational acc",
   "L" -> "Length"
   ];
```

You need the value of `"L"`? Call `value["L"]`. You need help on `"grav"`? Call `help["grav"]`. You want to know which variable names you have? Execute `Keys[value]`.

Comment: The problem is, as the code get complicated the variables name get closer to each other. So, by calling ss_1 it will give the gravity with out the need of memorizing the actual variable spelling.